# Access Report PageFooterSection_Format Not Firing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am looking for an event, in a report, that gets fired every time a page is created, as the report is being rendered.  I added a Page Footer to the report, then added code to

```
 PageFooterSection_Format
```

event.  I added a break point but the code is never fired.  I render the report like this:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "reportName", acViewReport, , , acHidden, !ID
```

Can anyone tell me why the event is not fired?  And if there is a better way to capture an event when a new page is added to a report?

thanks

Comment: Also, the report is unbound.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report section events don't fire in Report view `acViewReport`.

Only when printing or in Print preview.

There is also a `Report.OnPage` event, but that doesn't fire either.

If you think about it, the whole concept of "pages" only makes sense in Print views. Report view is more like a web page or a continuous form. There are no pages.

Comment: Is there another way to do this?  Here is what I am trying to do:  I have a DB that allows for the printing a large manual.  To accomplish this, I have a number of reports.  I programatically open these reports up, save them as a PDF then use Adobe PDF API to "stitch" all these files together.  Because these are all different files, I can't number the pages.  I also don't have a way to create book indexes, table of contents, etc.  But, If I can run some code every time a page, in each report, is created, I could add page numbers and save them in an array, to create the indexes.  Any other way?

Comment: @jason: Well, use `acViewPreview` instead of `acViewReport`. A PDF is based on pages, so print preview should be a more suitable view anyway.

Comment: The problem with opening in acViewPreview mode is that I can't assign controls, like TextBoxes, values at run time.  For instance:  Me.Textbox10.value = "some text" causes this error:  "You cant assign a value to this object".  This occurs on the Report_Load event

Comment: @jason: An unbound textbox? That works fine for me in Report_Load. Maybe ask a new question for this problem?